# How to pass json argument to a BGTaskScheduler

Tags: ios, swift, workmanagers, bgtaskscheduler

I would start a background task and give it an arguments which can be a json string.
On Android we can use something like :

```kotlin
val oneOffTaskRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker::class.java)
            .setInputData(buildTaskInputData(taskName, isInDebugMode, json))
```

How did that on IOS ?

```swift
let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(
  identifier: SwiftWorkmanagerPlugin.defaultBGProcessingTaskIdentifier
)
BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
```

Request didn't have attributes which seems to help...

Comment: What is your `BGTaskRequest`? How do you construct it? What does it do?

Comment: Currently, your request does nothing you just registered it. You should look at Apple sample code https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks?language=objc You need the `BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier:_:)` part

Comment: @Larme I already know that, I just didn't copy paste the 400 lines associated. I just wonder how to pass parameter to the background task process.

Comment: In `BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier:_:)` you create at some point an object that need your JSON (I guess a HTTP request), so that's where you put the parameter.

Comment: @Larme Ok i'm looking to find how achieve that.

This is actualy the code base, forked from the package workmanager.
https://github.com/EA-YOUHOU/flutter_workmanager/tree/bb6af7d342e122807c3909528760cc7eaf670a53/ios/Classes

Comment: @Larme i didn't achieve it, i just think it's not possible... Do you have a tips ?

Comment: I don't use flutter, but I guess subclass `BackgroundWorker` to set your parameter there...

Comment: @Larme This is not really flutter related, the subject here is around BGTaskScheduler and argument... Same issue for ReactNative or Swift native developpers.

Comment: You don't understand. You submit the task. Then, at some point, the closure of `register(forTaskWithIdentifier:using:launchHandler:)` is called and that's where you create your own background "real code" task. There, you put whatever parameter you want. You can just write : `let urlRequest = URLRequest(...), request.httpBody = someJSONParameter; myURLSession.dataTask...`

Comment: Funnily enough I'm creating a kmm project that uses WorkManager on Android and obviously the equivilent offered on iOS is BGTaskScheduler.  The 2 have the same fundemental goals, but the implementations are not very alike.  You cannot submit a BGProcessingTaskRequest with any parameters, like a task id or a task specific download url, that can later be extracted as task parameters from the BGProcessingTask object in the closure.  You are better off persisting any parameters when you submit a task and simply retrieve them from disk is the closure where you are provided the BGProcessingTask ...